# BERT sentence embeddings as input features for support vector regression

Tags: bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I used the bert-base-multilingual-cased Tokenizer and model to extract sentence embeddings from Instagram captions.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")

for caption in Captions[:10]:
    encoded_input = tokenizer(caption, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    caption_embeddings.append(output[0])
```

I then used tensor.detach().numpy().ravel() to make each embedding into a numpy array.

```
new_embeddings = []
vector = np.vectorize(np.float_)
for embedding in caption_embeddings:
    new_embeddings.append(vector(embedding.detach().numpy().ravel()))
```

However, if I try to pass this array into a Support Vector Regressor to predict number of likes on Instagram posts, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[205], line 1
----> 1 regr.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:405, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    403     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    404         fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 405         self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    407 return self

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py:192, in BaseLibSVM.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    190     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    191 else:
--> 192     X, y = self._validate_data(
    193         X,
    194         y,
    195         dtype=np.float64,
    196         order="C",
    197         accept_sparse="csr",
    198         accept_large_sparse=False,
    199     )
    201 y = self._validate_targets(y)
    203 sample_weight = np.asarray(
    204     [] if sample_weight is None else sample_weight, dtype=np.float64
    205 )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:584, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    582         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    583     else:
--> 584         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    585     out = X, y
    587 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1106, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1101         estimator_name = _check_estimator_name(estimator)
   1102     raise ValueError(
   1103         f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1104     )
-> 1106 X = check_array(
   1107     X,
   1108     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1109     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
   1110     dtype=dtype,
   1111     order=order,
   1112     copy=copy,
   1113     force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
   1114     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
   1115     allow_nd=allow_nd,
   1116     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
   1117     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
   1118     estimator=estimator,
   1119     input_name="X",
   1120 )
   1122 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
   1124 check_consistent_length(X, y)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:879, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    877         array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    878     else:
--> 879         array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
    880 except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    881     raise ValueError(
    882         "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    883     ) from complex_warning

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py:185, in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    182     xp, _ = get_namespace(array)
    183 if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184     # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185     array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186     return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187 else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[127], line 1
----> 1 X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
      2 y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py:140, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    138 @wraps(f)
    139 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    141     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    142         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    143         return (
    144             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    145             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    146         )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:878, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    874 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    875 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
    876 if y is None:
    877     # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 878     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    879 else:
    880     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
    881     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py:824, in StandardScaler.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    822 # Reset internal state before fitting
    823 self._reset()
--> 824 return self.partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py:861, in StandardScaler.partial_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    858 self._validate_params()
    860 first_call = not hasattr(self, "n_samples_seen_")
--> 861 X = self._validate_data(
    862     X,
    863     accept_sparse=("csr", "csc"),
    864     dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
    865     force_all_finite="allow-nan",
    866     reset=first_call,
    867 )
    868 n_features = X.shape[1]
    870 if sample_weight is not None:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:565, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    563     raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    564 elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 565     X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
    566     out = X
    567 elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:879, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    877         array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    878     else:
--> 879         array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
    880 except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    881     raise ValueError(
    882         "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    883     ) from complex_warning

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py:185, in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    182     xp, _ = get_namespace(array)
    183 if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184     # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185     array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186     return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187 else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried using vector = np.vectorize(np.float_) but without success. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the embeddings in this way:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
caption_embeddings = []

for caption in Captions[:10]:
    encoded_input = tokenizer(caption, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    caption_embeddings.append(output[0][:,0,:])  # Only keep the [CLS] token output

new_embeddings = []
for embedding in caption_embeddings:
    new_embeddings.append(embedding.detach().numpy().ravel())
new_embeddings = np.array(new_embeddings)
```

Afterwards, make sure your X and y variables are properly formatted before using them in fit_transform. They should be 2D numpy arrays with a consistent shape, where each row represents an instance and columns represent features.

For your new_embeddings, set y to something like:

```
y = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)
```